# How to count rows with the same value in Tableau

Tags: count, tableau-api

I have a file with the following values:

```
column1        column2  
quiebre        Madrid  
no_quiebre     Barcelona  
quiebre        Madrid  
no_quiebre     Barcelona  
quiebre        Barcelona  
no_quiebre     Madrid  
no_quiebre     Madrid
```

and I need to calculate three variables in Tableau (`column3`, `column4` and `column5`), the first one (`column3`) should count the number of times the city appear in the entire file and give the following result:

```
column1       column2        column3    
quiebre        Madrid          4  
no_quiebre     Barcelona       3  
quiebre        Madrid          4  
no_quiebre     Barcelona       3  
quiebre        Barcelona       3  
no_quiebre     Madrid          4  
no_quiebre     Madrid          4
```

The second variable (`column4`) should add the number of (`quiebre`) per city:

```
column1       column2        column3   column4  
quiebre        Madrid          4         2  
no_quiebre     Barcelona       3         1  
quiebre        Madrid          4         2  
no_quiebre     Barcelona       3         1  
quiebre        Barcelona       3         1  
no_quiebre     Madrid          4         2  
no_quiebre     Madrid          4         2
```

and finally the third variable calculates the ratio between `column4` and `column3`, I mean `column4 / column3 * 100`

Any clue about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Column 3 should look like ->

```
column3 = Count(column2)
```

Now Join column1 and column2 call it joined column.

Then create column4 it should look like ->

```
column4 = Count(column1+column2)
```

Arrange them on the tableau worksheet so that you get the desired result.